# Can I push webforms pages and/or other content into another assembly outside of the webapp project?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, webforms

I would like to start pulling out pages that meet certain criteria from the main assembly into a referenced assembly, while we transition the project to MVC.

Alternatively, I could create a fresh MVC project and just reference this assembly's pages/static content if that is possible. How would I go about it either way?

I'm thinking legacy `.js`,`.css` static content.
Also `aspx`, `aspx.cs`, `ascx.cs`, `ascx.designer.cs`, `aspx.designer.cs` and `ascx`pages that are functionally ready to be obsoleted for mvc `.cshtml` versions.

Oh and ESPECIALLY all references to 3rd party User controls.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% confident this will help, but in short I would ask:

Why don't you pull the logic of the Handler, WebPage into another class library and in aspx/ahsx header set the referencing class to the class library's namespace. If the class library is in your bin (referenced) I don't see a problem.

With static content, I don't see why you would move it to another assembly as it is not in an assembly to start with (served by IIS). If you must move it you will need to write a proxy class to make the needed io to read the file(s) and send to the response stream.

Comment: static content out to cleanly show stuff that may go away once the things that need them go away.